# How to correct grainy caramel corn?

Tags: caramel, corn

I have never had trouble with this simple recipe for caramel corn until now so it is a mystery.  Everything looked great(smooth consistency and taste) as I was mixing it with the popcorn right up until I take it out of the oven to give it a stir.  That is when I noticed it was no longer smooth, moist and even a bit dry.
When it was done I put it out to cool as I always do, then immediately stored it properly.
As I was laying it out, it remained rather dry just as it was when first pulling it out of oven for a stir.
There was grainy brown sugar left on the surface where it was cooling.  Very perplexed.

Comment: Would you post the recipe and steps you used? Are your kitchen temperature, humidity, and other conditions the same as for the previous batches?